# How to create dynamic naming for each controls on userform in sub routine?

Tags: vba

I want to create a routine that when called will perform the function base on the control names dynamically. Here's my code:

```
Private Sub myControl(counter as string)
    If mySecondControl & counter.Value = "Y" Then
        myThirdControl & counter.Caption = "Do Something Here" 'Error syntax
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub doThis_Change()
    myControl("1")
    myControl("2")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the `Control` you want from the form's `Controls` collection:

```
If Controls("mySecondControl" & counter).Value = "Y" Then
    Controls("myThirdControl" & counter).Caption = "Do Something Here"
End If
```

Comment: Ok I see what you're doing. But "set the form name" isn't what OP needs to do. They need to access the control from the `Controls` collection, and work with that `Control` object... like that code is doing. That `With MyFormName` is poisonous, it works against *the default instance* and the controls are quite possibly not on *that* instance. You want `With Me` instead, which is entirely redundant, so remove the `With` block and just do `If Controls("...")` instead. Working against forms' default instance is going to bite you in the rear end one day or another. Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but With Me entirely redundant? Never heard that before.

Comment: Because `Me` refers to *the current instance* of the class, so you *already* have access to all its members directly - `With Me` isn't buying you anything at all, it's not exposing anything that isn't already accessible. Actually, `With Me` won't let you access any of the private members that you can already access without it, so it's actually harmful.